# Как обойти запрет на хотлинкинг?

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Нужно получить доступ к изображению\видео по ссылке, но проблема в том что этот сайт сделал защиту от хотлинкинга и напрямую изображение через скрипт, используя лишь ссылку на него, я получить не могу.
Есть ли какие-то варианты обхода данного ограничения или варианты как хотя бы выяснить чем оно вызвано?
При попытках получить данные через file_get_contents всегда выбивает ошибку HTTP/503, однако если вставлять ссылку напрямую в браузере, то все открывает.Как быть?

Comment: обрабатывать редиректы, прописать юзер агент из браузера

Comment: Пробую через curl подобным образом и прописываю юзер агент там же, все равно 503 выдает :/